# Новый знак на SO: РУ возможно ли?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, знаки

Стало разрешено публиковать статистику по успешному лечению онко-больных. Впрочем, неважно, каких именно больных. Но, минимум, три человека SO:RU сделали вклад в то, чтобы тысячи людей прожили дольше. Нельзя ли для них сделать знак/медаль? Это несложно, как я понимаю, но им будет очень приятно, что их навыки/умения помогли другим людям прожить дольше/выжить/ в принципе, жить.

Если подробнее, то последние 9 лет мы занимаемся исследованиями по предсказанию и раннему обнаружению ряда наследственных заболеваний, в том числе онкологических. В процессе исследований вставали (и встают) разные задачи, некоторые были успешно решены на SO:РУ. А результат решения 2х задач постоянно используется и эффект очевиден: годы жизни, новые жизни.

Вот эти 2 задачи:

[Как правильно построить работу с БД, хранящей огромные данные генома человека?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778781/)

Создание данной базы (она бесплатна для коллег при соблюдении определенных протоколов) дало возможность упростить поиск патогенных мутаций, сделать его более точным. Взамен мы от коллег просили расширенную статистику использования. Я поднял вопрос этичности ее публикации, и, поскольку она анонимизирована, я могу сообщить, что случаев ремиссии/отступления болезни набралось за всё время с момента создания - 2600+

[Нахождение минимального набора вырожденных последовательностей ДНК](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026989/)

Здесь я сожалею, что до сих пор не вышла публикация по данному вопросу (увы, не в моей компетенции решать политические вопросы), но решение задачи сейчас - в основе универсального поисковика праймеров, которым пользуются многие мои коллеги. И тут спасибо должны говорить не только онко-больные, но часто и просто те, кому быстрый анализ помог не глотать лишних таблеток, а сразу применить оптимальное решение.

Понятно, что так или иначе, рано или поздно они были бы решены, но поскольку решены они были именно "рано", в нужный момент, то и эффект оказался серьёзным.

Поэтому я и бы и хотел вынести на рассмотрение новый знак - за реальный вклад в процесс спасения жизни и здоровья.

Да, ожидаю вопроса "А судьи кто?", то есть, каким образом понять, что человек заслужил этот знак. Тут только экспертное мнение, увы.

Comment: Для тех, кто хочет накидать минусов: эта идея на самом деле не так абсурдна, как кажется. На GitHub например, делали специальный значок для внесших вклад в проекты, используемые NASA в исследованиях Марса: https://github.blog/2021-04-19-open-source-goes-to-mars/

Comment: Люди которые давали ответы по ссылкам, при всём моём уважении, просто решали интересную задачку. А то что решения как-то повлияли на жизнь других людей, это скорее заслуга Ваша и ваших коллег.

Comment: 1. Коротко опишите на что повлияли решения в самом вопросе.
2. Переименуйте вопросы. Что за название "Как оптимизировать таблицы/запрос в MySQL?". "Оптимизация таблицы повторов человеческого генома" уже поинтереснее будет?

Comment: @4per 1. Сделано 2. А какая разница? :) Плюс ваше название меньше, на мой вкус, отражает фабулу вопроса.

Comment: А я то думаю, почему мне на старый ответ плюсы сыпятся, а это вон оно что :) Очень рад, что решение пригодилось! Знаки конечно хорошо, но понимание, что прямо сейчас этот код помогает людям на практике с вопросами их здоровья, особенно в такой области - для меня уже награда!

Comment: @ViktorTomilov большая разница. Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке.
Заголовок — это первое, что увидят читатели, которые могут ответить на ваш вопрос. Если заголовок неинтересный, они не будут читать дальше.

Comment: @Зонтик убедили :)

Comment: Не разводите детсад...

Comment: Оказывается есть [`https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/`](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/). Так что давать значки в первую очередь надо там :)

Answer (score 7):

Сначала я хочу уточнить, а что же такое "знаки" на сайтах Stack Exchange. [Знаки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) (badges) - это ассоциированные с профилем участника награды, которые в подавляющем большинстве случаев выдаются автоматически (т.е. не требуют участия живого человека) на основании выполнения определённых критериев. Единственным особенным знаком на текущий момент является знак ["Не робот"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/196/not-a-robot), который требует дополнительных телодвижений от менеджера сообщества, т.е. человека, являющегося сотрудником компании на зарплате.

Поэтому, как мне кажется, чтобы предлагать какой-то новый знак, нужно формализовать критерий его получения и критерий этот должен быть машинно-вычислимым, т.е. не требовать участия живых людей. В текущей формулировке это не выглядит выполнимым.

Отдельный вопрос, что предлагается знак, уникальный для конкретного сайта. Это вторая серьёзная проблема. Я не знаю подобных прецедентов на других сайтах сети.

Таким образом, перспективы создания нового знака с учётом обозначенных особенностей, довольно плачевны. Единственным подходящим вариантом видится знак-за-метку, но учитывая ничтожное кол-во вопросов и, как следствие, существенно ограниченное кол-во голосов, необходимое для получения знака за метку, получить такой знак, даже "бронзовый" (100 баллов рейтинга и не менее 20 вопросов), малореально.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать метку "Вклад-в-науку". Вешать её только при наличии пруф-линков в вопросе. Лучшим отвечающим - респект и уважуха. Может когда-нибудь даже бронзовый знак будет получен, и мы будем понимать, что такой бронзовый дороже иных золотых.

Comment: Метки нужны для поиска, а не для награды участников. Можно ввести метку [tag:днк] или [tag:медицина]. А для награждения нужен именно [знак](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Comment: ну знака не будет, это же очевидно или нет? Если метки только для поиска зачем знаки за метки и привилегии обладателям золотого знака?

Comment: Пожалуй, я несколько поторопился при прочтении ответа, и на самом деле идея хорошая, НО: 1)  название метки, предложенное вами, не кажется мне корректным 2) пруф-линки лишние

Comment: Ну, ежели я правильно понимаю, знака не будет. Такое решение тоже оправдано

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12820/#comment55732_12825

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Можно начать с того, чтобы сделать минимально возможное в рамках существующих правил: 1. Разместить на сайтах организаций-разработчиков информацию вида "В разработке нашего ПО помог такой-то ответ со Stackoverlow". 2. В комментариях к ответам разместить ссылки на эту страницу, с пояснением вида "Данный ответ использовался в разработке ПО, используемого в медицине". Если примеров такого будет много, можно будет обосновать и создание специального знака.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight В этом плане я готов начать работать. К сожалению, такому варианту могут начать противодействовать стандартные научные ссылочные системы, в т.ч. РАН. Попробую

Answer (score -2):

#### Почему специального знака "за спасение жизни и здоровья" не будет

Новый знак - это новый функционал. Некоторый функционал, добавленный на enSO, на ruSO до сех пор отсутствует (например, если вы давно не голосовали за вопросы, но только что проголосовали за ответ - то вылезает подсказка, что мол, вопросами тоже нужны голоса). А это значит, что и новым знаком специально для ruSO заниматься не будут. Да и для всей сети не будут: [в последнее время компания совершенно не слушает сообщество](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/). Сообщество было против [новых кнопок голосования](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/), но его не послушали. Сообщество было против [новой политики о запрете модератором удаления gpt-контента](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/), но его проигнорировали. С чего бы в этот раз что-то поменяется?

#### Но есть альтернатива!

В качестве альтернативы можно "допилить" вариант @4per. Вместо метки [вклад-в-науку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%83) можно создать метку [медицина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0) и лучшие отвечающие по этой метке действительно будут получать знак за эту метку. "пруф-линков" не надо. А метку эту можно прикреплять как и остальные другие.

#### Дополнение

@ViktorTomilov заметил в комментарии, что нужная метка уже существует, и её название подходит больше, чем просто "медицина" - это метка [биоинформатика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0). Поэтому метка [медицина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0) не требуется. Кстати, у [биоинформатика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) есть описание.

Comment: А можно и оба варианта использовать Ваш и мой. Ваш, на мой взгляд обсуждения вообще не требует, что кому мешает создать метку медицина (генетика?) прямо сейчас.

Comment: Так есть метка биоинформатика. И она использована в вопросах. Не шило на мыло?